# Converting C dll header to delphi: char*

Tags: c, delphi, pointers, nidaqmx

I'm using an NIDAQmx DLL in a Delphi XE4 app.  The DLL only has an ANSI C header file.

I'm trying to convert this function:

```
int32 __CFUNC DAQmxGetPhysicalChanName(TaskHandle taskHandle, 
        const char channel[], char *data, uInt32 bufferSize);
```

This is my translation:

```
function DAQmxGetPhysicalChanName(taskHandle: TTaskHandle;
        chanName: PAnsiChar; chanPhysName: PAnsiChar;
        bufferSize: DWORD): Integer; stdcall; external NI_DLL_NAME delayed;
```

When I call it like this:

```
var    
  s1,s2:  String[200];
  sp: PAnsiChar;
begin
// sp:=@s2[1]; When I uncomment this, fucntion works as
//  expected, otherwice return string s2 is empty!
   res:=DAQmxGetPhysicalChanName(taskHandle,@s1[1],@s2[1],200);
```

The function works only when I insert `sp:=@s2[1]` before the call.  I never actually use the `sp` pointer, but just the fact that it get assigned helps. Without that, the `s2` string is empty.  I cant understand why.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `s1, s2: array[0..199] of AnsiChar` instead of `s1, s2: String[200]`, and then replace `@s1[1]` and `@s2[1]` with `@s1[0]` and `@s2[0]`, or just `s1` and `s2` without any indexing.

Comment: Thanks, just tested - it works correctly! But I dont really understand what's the difference? In both cases we pass pointers to arrays of bytes, which arrays calling DLL fills as null-terminated string? I mean, are C types  const char and char * equal while translating in Delphi and equal to Pascal byte (char) array?

Comment: `String[200]` defines a 200-character `ShortString`, which is physically 201 bytes in memory. The first byte is the string length. You are passing a pointer to the string's character memory, and the function can populate that with data all it wants, but you are not setting the string length byte afterwards, so it is still 0, giving the illusion that the string is blank. A raw `array[] of AnsiChar` has no such length byte.

Comment: Oh, now its clear, many thanks! Just forgot about that length might be incorrect.